# How to remove header and footer from specific pages in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I want to remove header and footer for some specific pages in Microsoft Word 2007. I know that I can use "different first page" to remove header and footer for first page, but I want to remove them for specific pages. Is there any way?

Comment: After consulting a very knowledgeable person on the subject, it is not something you can do. The most you can do in the header/footer is remove from the first page or alternating odd/even pages. If you want something else you might be able to fake it using footnotes in the body of the page.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't unlink the header/footer before the pages you want to remove them for and then duplicate the header and footer manually for the subsequent pages you want them on?

Answer (score 1):

Header and footer are Section dependent. One section has a single header/footer. So you will have to split your document into sections. Then configure each section for the kind of header/footer you want there.

Comment: This is correct. To elaborate on how that is done, insert a section break prior to the page where you want the different header/footer text, open the header/footer design tool by double-clicking in the header area of the document and format as needed.