# Manually changing footers

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a document that needs footers edited. It needs to be page numbered. I need the first two pages to NOT show a footer, yet the third page to have the footer reflect page 3, and so on from there. I can't seem to find anything besides removing the footer on the first page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove header from the 2 first pages in document?](http://superuser.com/questions/452418/how-can-i-remove-header-from-the-2-first-pages-in-document), also see: [How to remove header and footer from specific pages in Microsoft Word](http://superuser.com/questions/764950/how-to-remove-header-and-footer-from-specific-pages-in-microsoft-word)

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/578165/354511) to [How can I have different text in the footer on every page of a Word document?](https://superuser.com/q/47345/354511):

- Edit the footer.
- Copy the following text:

  ```
   IF PAGE > 2 "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
  ```

  into the footer. 
  Replace the “lazy dog” sentence with the text that you want to include starting on page 3. 
  It can be multiple lines.  If you want it to include the dynamic page number,
  type the word `PAGE`, then select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
  This will convert the word `PAGE` into a page number field, which will temporarily
  add `{` and `}` to the display, resulting in something like this: `{ PAGE }`

  (I don’t know what to do if your footer contains literal quote characters, or non-text elements like images.)
- Select the word `PAGE` (at the beginning) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Select the entire phrase and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
  This will convert those strings to fields, and, consequently,
  add (more) `{` and `}` characters, resulting in something like this:

  ```
  { IF { PAGE } > 2 "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." }
  ```
- Right-click on the `IF` and select “Toggle Field Codes”.
- If there’s anything that you want in the footer on every page, add it now.
- Close the footer.

## Explanation

<sup>(In case any is needed)</sup>

Basically, this is Microsoft Word’s implementation of the `IF`-`THEN`-`ELSE` construct
that is common in programming languages, as in

```
IF  Todays’s date is 1
THEN
    Today is Monday
ELSE IF  Todays’s date is 2
THEN
    Today is Tuesday
ELSE IF  Todays’s date is 3
THEN
    Today is Wednesday
ELSE
    Here comes the weekend!
END IF
```

Generally, they can all be nested (as shown in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/578165/354511)).